# what to do with the .epub file in epub.js

Tags: javascript, epub

i'm confused as to how i could implement **epub.js**.

(https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/blob/master/documentation/README.md) i'm having a hard time understanding the documentation since i'm new. I tried following the demo files and folders and the "basic" example file but i noticed the paths direct to a folder named "OPS" which has a file for every chapter and others.

so i'm stuck on what to do with the .epub files and how to get a folder like that given my epub files.

Answer (score 2):

simply change file extension of .epub to .zip and unpack yours books. When you done that, edit this part:

```
var Book = ePub("url/to/book/"); // With default options
```

where and give it path to your book.